# Store and view list of whitelisted contacts

Tags: java, android

What would be a simple way to store a list of contacts? I don't need to store much, just a unique identifier for each contact.
I'm picking my contacts by Intent.ACTION_PICK

Could this be done using build in contact groups? Can I create an invisible group and add contacts to that group?

A database and a loader seems a bit overkill... or is that just the way it's done?

The list of contacts will be presented to the user in a ListActivity or a ListFragment. And the entire app will pretty much be three views; whitelist, blacklist and pick contact. Filtering each view so any given contact only appears in one view (or list or group).

Any syggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I'm trying to use the build in contact groups. However I have a few bugs that I need to sort out before I can update this post with some code. If this hasn't happened a few weeks after this post was made feel free to send me a message.